# Conditionally change color of html element

Tags: html, css, .net, angular, razor

How can I conditionally change the color of this html element:

so far I have tried this @{
string headerBackground = ViewBag.IsPremium && !ViewBag.IsXUser ? "#0272B9" : "#0091BA";
}

I was expecting for the banner to sort of implement a ternary operand and if it's a premium user choose the first color, if not choose the second.

Thanks,

Comment: This should work 
`{ string headerBackground = ViewBag.IsPremium ? "#0272B9" : "#0091BA"; }`